# Moving average for 3 weeks with lookback starting from Sunday of 2 week's back to current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, teradata

I want to find the moving average for three weeks. But here the catch is for everyday( of current week) it should be calculated tracing back to Sunday of 2 weeks(it starts from last to last Sunday and does not incluse current week's Sunday) and then calculating till current day.

Below is the sample data.

There is one entry per day in the Date column. And we need to calculate the moving average per project per LOB.
For simplicity I have taken only one project and 1 LOB and three weeks data.

[image]

Below is the expected output:

[image]

**Explanation:**

For 20th July , it fetches data starting from 5th July(Sunday from 2 weeks back) till 20th July. So it adds up the sales for the period which is 44000 and then divides it by the number of days, which is 16. Same way for 21st July , it starts from 5th July to 21st July, cumulative sales for the period being 45000 and number of days is 17 (so 45000/17 =  2647.05) and so on.

I am struggling altering the typical window function query to achieve this:

```
avg(sales) over(partition by project,lob order by date rows 21 preceding)
```

Comment: SQL Server and Teradata are two different database products. Please tag only the one database that you are running.

Comment: Primarily this requirement is for sql-server . But I am also looking for a Teradata way to do it since I replicated the same and could not achieve it there. Its for my learning I tagged both.

Comment: This is a confusingly hard problem, because you want the window frame to begin on a week boundary, but you don't want it to end one one.  Plus, the standard definition of week usually starts on Mondays and not Sundays, further complicating a solution.

Comment: You can't use rows preceding, at least not how you are trying it here.  The number will change for every row, it sounds like.

Comment: Why not just use a subquery?

Comment: Please elaborate on the logic around excluding the current week's Sunday.

Comment: I noticed the rows # proceding is the number preceding rows from current.   Avg(FieldValue) over(partition by Field1,Field2
 order by Field1,Field2 desc,Field3 desc rows 8 preceding) NineWeekAvg,

Answer (score 2):

This is a Teradata solution, which could be easily ported to SQL Server (only `td_sunday` is Teradata syntax, returning the previous sunday, used to define weeks). The logic is simple, based on avg = sum/count: Calculate weekly data, use this for the previous two weeks and add the current weeks cumulative sales.

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT t.*
     -- sum/count per week 
     ,SUM  (sales) OVER (PARTITION BY lob, project, td_sunday(dt)) AS week_sum
     ,COUNT(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY lob, project, td_sunday(dt)) AS week_cnt
     -- cumulative sum/count for current week
     ,SUM  (sales) OVER (PARTITION BY lob, project, td_sunday(dt)
                         ORDER BY dt ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)     AS cum_sum
     ,COUNT(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY lob, project, td_sunday(dt)
                         ORDER BY dt ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)     AS cum_cnt
   FROM vt as t
 )
SELECT cte.*
  ,CASE -- both weeks before exist
      WHEN     LAG(week_cnt,14) OVER (PARTITION BY lob, project ORDER BY dt) = 7
      THEN
        CAST( -- sum of the previous two weeks + current week
             ( LAG(week_sum, 7) OVER (PARTITION BY lob, project ORDER BY dt) -- previous week
              +LAG(week_sum,14) OVER (PARTITION BY lob, project ORDER BY dt) -- two weeks before
              +cum_sum
             ) as decimal(38,3)
            ) / 
        -- number of rows in previous two weeks + current week
        (cum_cnt + 14) 
      ELSE 0
    END
FROM cte
ORDER BY dt;
```

Quite efficient in Teradata, Explain shows only two *STAT FUNCTION steps`.

Btw, it's not exactly your expected result, because it returns an average for July 19, too. But this could be fixed with some additional logic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a week number to your table or time dimension, then define your window based on the week number, and not the day.

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL (June 7 is a prior Sunday):

```
with DateWindows as (
 select DateColumn, dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, '2020-06-07', DateColumn)-2, '2020-06-07') as SundayStartingDate
 from MyDateTable
)
select DW.DateColumn, DW.SundayStartingDate, count(*) as DaysCount, sum(Sales) as RollingSalesAmt, avg(Sales) as RollingAvgSalesAmt
from DateWindows DW
join MyDateTable T on DW.DateColumn between DW.SundayStartingDate and DW.DateColumn
group by DW.DateColumn between DW.SundayStartingDate
order by DW.DateColumn;
```

2020-07-20 = {44000, 16, 2750}
2020-07-21 = {45000, 17, 2647}
...etc...

Answer (score 0):

There's always brute force :

```
select
    "date", sales, lob, project,
    sum(sales) over (partition by lob, project order by "date" rows between 13 preceding and current row) +
    case when datepart(weekday, "date") >= 1 then lag(sales, 14) over (partition by lob, project order by "date") else 0 end +
    case when datepart(weekday, "date") >= 2 then lag(sales, 15) over (partition by lob, project order by "date") else 0 end +
    case when datepart(weekday, "date") >= 3 then lag(sales, 16) over (partition by lob, project order by "date") else 0 end +
    case when datepart(weekday, "date") >= 4 then lag(sales, 17) over (partition by lob, project order by "date") else 0 end +
    case when datepart(weekday, "date") >= 5 then lag(sales, 18) over (partition by lob, project order by "date") else 0 end +
    case when datepart(weekday, "date") >= 6 then lag(sales, 19) over (partition by lob, project order by "date") else 0 end +   
    case when datepart(weekday, "date") >= 7 then lag(sales, 20) over (partition by lob, project order by "date") else 0 end
    ) / (14.0 + datepart(weekday, "date")) as rolling_avg
from t;
```

This does assume that `@@datefirst` is set to Sunday so adjust as needed.

https://rextester.com/RASTH4795